# REGEX - using finditer()

Tags: python, regex

Let's say I have a string `abbb`. I am trying to print the following pattern using regex:

```
a
ab
abb
abbb
```

I tried doing:

```
import re
line = "abbb"
m = re.finditer('ab*',line)
for i in m:
    print i.group(1)
```

This does not work. In the python docs it says `ab*` will match `a`, `ab`, or `a` followed by any number of `b`s. I was thinking `finditer()` would store all the different matches in a list like `[a,ab,...,abbb]`. There are very limited examples of `finditer()` on the net. How can I achieve this? Please note that I need to use regex.

Comment: if theres 0 match of b it will return only a. not match a.

Comment: *"In the python docs they said the"* -- This means that your regular expression will match `line = 'a'`, `line = 'ab'` or `line = 'abbb...'`. It does not mean that ill will return all possible valid lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An other regex way, that reverses the string before and that uses a reversed pattern enclosed in a lookahead to get overlapped matches:

```
>>> s = 'abbb'
>>> [i[::-1] for i in reversed(re.findall(r'(?=(b*a))', s[::-1]))]
```

Answer (score 1):

Regex won't help you achieve what you want.
For patterns like `ab*` and lines like `abbbbb` you can do something like this:

```
from itertools import combinations
line= "abbb"
for x in range(1, len(line)+1):
    print "".join(list(combinations(line, x))[0])
```

**OUTPUT**

```
a
ab
abb
abbb
```

Note that this is a special case, and it will probably won't be a good solution for more complex patterns!

---

**Using Regex**

```
import re

text= "abbb"
pattern = re.compile('ab*')

e = 1
while True and e < len(text)+1:
    match = pattern.search(text, 0, e)
    if not match:
        break
    s = match.start()
    print text[s:e]
    e += 1
```

**OUTPUT**

```
a
ab
abb
abbb
```

Comment: hey, i tried but theres no difference. It still prints abbb. I want it to print {a,ab,abb,abbb} thanks.